# Как использовать клавиатуру ReplyKeyboardRemove на питоне

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot

Необходимо удалить (не убрать) ReplyKeyboardMarkup клавиатуру после нажатия. Использование конструкции

```
keyboard = types.ReplyKeyboardRemove()
keyboard.row('Профиль', 'Контакты', 'Назад')
```

Не работает, говорит, что метод row не может быть использован для данной клавиатуры.

Вопрос: как реализовать удаление клавиатуры после нажатия на нее?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

не требуется указывать какую именно клавиатуру нужно удалить

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def selfmyself(message):
    service = telebot.types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(True, True)
    service.row('Wunderlist')
    service.row('Telegraph')
    service.row('Погода')
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Что будем делать?', reply_markup=service)


@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def handle_text(message):
    if message.text == "Wunderlist":
        a = telebot.types.ReplyKeyboardRemove()
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Что', reply_markup=a)
```