# Как удалить кнопки в телеграм боте

Tags: python

Вот есть кнопки в боте:

```
markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
item1 = types.KeyboardButton("Да")
item2 = types.KeyboardButton("Нет")
markup.add(item1, item2)
bot.send_message(message.from_user.id,' текст  ', reply_markup=markup)
```

Мне нужно, чтобы после того, как на них тыкнули они удалялись.
Это телеграм бот.
Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[уже было](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1123888/234134):

```
   @bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
    def selfmyself(message):
        service = telebot.types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(True, True)
        service.row('Wunderlist')
        service.row('Telegraph')
        service.row('Погода')
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Что будем делать?', reply_markup=service)


    @bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
    def handle_text(message):
        if message.text == "Wunderlist":
            a = telebot.types.ReplyKeyboardRemove()
            bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Что', reply_markup=a)
```